# Math in Django to get a total returned

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I'm trying to get to a result that tells me something like 10.5 hours worked on a project.

here's what I'm doing in my view:

```
time = Time.objects.filter(my_company=my_company, project=project)
raw_hours = time.aggregate(Sum('hours'))
raw_minutes = time.aggregate(Sum('minutes'))
adj_minutes = raw_minutes.raw_minutes__sum / 100
hours = adj_minutes + raw_hours.raw_hours__sum
return {'hours': hours}
```

When I add `{{ view.hours }}` to my template, I'm not seeing anything in the return. I'm expecting `view.hours == 10.5` or something like that depending on the math.

So I have two questions. Am I thinking about this correctly and is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Have you tried simply `{{ hours }}`?

Comment: So, to clarify, this is a different way of doing get_context_data. So instead of having to write a get_context_data each time you can just write a method that attaches to the view. http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html

Comment: So, it has to be {{ view.hours }}

Comment: Got it! Cool stuff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get both aggregates by doing:

```
d = time.aggregate(Sum('hours'), Sum('minutes'))
```

this should return a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'hours__sum' : Decimal('10'), 'minutes__sum' : Decimal('630')}
```

so to access the values you should deal with it the same way as you deal with any other dictionary.

```
hours = d['hours__sum']
```

On the template, you only need to provide the key for the context dictionary, in your case:

```
{{ hours }}
```

Comment: I was making things too complicated and I had the wrong syntax.